# Best way to make a ConnectionRequest in Android

Tags: android, codenameone

I coded this connection request using codenameone. I will like to know the best way to do the same thing on android. Any help please. I have searched around and not really getting anything solid. This is what I want to do. Thanks.

public void doLogin(String username, String password) {

```
    ConnectionRequest cr;
    cr = new ConnectionRequest() {
        Hashtable h;

        @Override
        protected void postResponse() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            h = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
            System.out.println("" + h);
            String username = (String) h.get("username");

            if (username != null) {
                user = username;
                showForm("Dashboard", null);

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
            if (code == 401) {
                Dialog.show("Failure", "Invalid Username or Password", "OK", null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void handleException(Exception err) {
            Dialog.show("Failure", "Check Network", "OK", null);
        }

    };

    cr.addRequestHeader(AppConfig.REQUEST_HEADER, AppConfig.REQUEST_HEADER_VALUE);
    cr.setContentType(AppConfig.CONTENT_TYPE);
    cr.setUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL + "authentication?username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
    cr.setPost(true);
    cr.setReadResponseForErrors(true);
    InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
    Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
    cr.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(cr);

}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow the question, this connection request should work on Android just fine why would you need to do it separately on Android?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Well there is this project I'm working on and I would like to include a bluetooth printer support but then using codenameone's bluetooth plugin. It doesn't even display any devices available when the search is clicked. The same with BTDemo on github it does the same thing. Also codenameone's simulator doesn't support all that and I will have to keep sending builds on and on to debug. Also I would just like to know how to do the request on android separately

Answer (score 0):

We support BluetoothLE which is where the industry is going. I would suggest avoiding that entirely for this use case and using a native interface to the OS's printing API's which are currently unmapped in Codename One.

For Android you can use the standard `java.net.URL` code and the `org.json` parsing API.

Comment: If I could get an Example please

Comment: I don't do Android development that isn't Codename One so I don't have stuff like that lying around and it's quite a bit of code.